# What is the limit on the machine name in window server?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008

I need to store the machine name in a database field, so I need to know how big to make the field.

So is there a limit on the length of a machine name?

If so what is the limit?

Can I machine name be Unicode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This KB article says 255 bytes for the FQDN and it does support Unicode.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/909264

> **DNS domain names**
>
> The maximum length of the host name
>   and of the fully qualified domain name
>   (FQDN) is 63 octets per label and 255
>   bytes per FQDN. This maximum includes
>   254 bytes for the FQDN and one byte
>   for the ending dot.
>
> In Windows 2000 and in Windows Server
>   2003, the maximum host name and the
>   FQDN use the standard length
>   limitations that are mentioned
>   earlier, with the addition of UTF-8
>   (Unicode) support. Because some UTF-8
>   characters exceed one octet in length,
>   you cannot determine the size by
>   counting the characters.

Answer (score 1):

[RFC 1035](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1035.html) says 63 characters. Tried it on a XP box and it would only allow 63 characters..